# Vision API Product Search

Tags: python, google-cloud-vision

I've implemented Vision API Product Search for my project in which I upload photos of a clothing piece and try to find the similar clothes. Vision API used to worked well when I only had grey and white clothes in my training set, but when I added colorful clothes in the training set, it doesn't work at all! Is there anyone who faced the same/a similar problem?

Comment: we should add training and testing sets while using vision product  search api ? i thought this api do all the work for me, i only upload images and then they will come back with the similar photos!

Answer (score 0):

You could try the Image Properties feature of Vision API which detects general attributes of the image, such as dominant color. [1](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/detecting-properties#vision_image_property_detection-python)